# How to test if a variable is set?

Tags: java, variables

In PHP, there is a `isset` function. What about Java? I think I can use `== null` with objects, but what about value types like `int`

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Chances are that there's a better way than relying on (possibly ambiguous) default values.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Java's compiler won't let you define variables and use them before they were assigned a value, so the problem doesn't exist in the same form as it exists in php.

#### EDIT

If in your case the compiler didn't stop you already (because this is eg an instance variable) the best solution is probably to initialize the variable to some "special" value as suggested by Guest11239193.  Like this:

```
int x = 0; // because by convention 0 is a reasonable default here
```

Of course, what a "safe, reasonable" initialization value is depends on the application.

Afterwards, you could

```
if (x == 0) { // only allow setting if x has its initial value
    x = somenewvalue;
}
```

Or you could access x via a setter that inhibits changing more than once (probably overkill for most cases):

```
private int x;
private boolean x_was_touched = false;

public void setX (int newXvalue) {
    if (!x_was_touched) {
       x = newXvalue;
       x_was_touched = true;
    }
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
```

You could also use an `Integer`, int's object brother, which could be initialized to null

```
Integer x = null;
```

However, the fact that you think you need that knowledge may hide a deeper logic flaw in your program, so I'd suggest you explore the reason why you want to know if a primitive value (primitive as opposed to objects, `int` vs `Integer`) wasn't touched.

Comment: Suppose I defined a variables `int x`. I want to set it only if its not already set, how might you do that?

Comment: @jiewmeng The only way you could do that is if you have a "magic value" that means "this hasn't been set yet", or you set a flag when you set the property via a setter method. As others are saying, what you want doesn't really make sense in Java.

Comment: I ran into this by using `args[0]` in my little hello world [program](http://codetidy.com/7834/). In PHP I would do an `isset()` here or set a default value in the function declaration, what's common in Java?

Comment: @adityamenon as args is an array you could just use args.length to test whether there was a command line argument - like this `System.out.println("Hello World! Hello " + ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : "you forgot to enter something on the command line") + "!");`

Comment: What if I want to access a variable in a `finally` block? The variable may or may not be defined in the try block. In fact code may or may not have reached to the variable definition.

Comment: @HPM that's a scenario that, if I understand correctly what you're saying, won't happen because the compiler will not take variable initialisations in the try or catch block into account when looking at the "finally" block. Try it, you'll see that the code will not compile if the only initialisations are inside the try or catch block.

Answer (score 11):

A non-existing variable doesn't exist in Java.

Answer (score 5):

In Java it is a compiler error to use a variable without being set.

Class and instance variables are initialized with what is considered a default "null" value, depending on the data type.

So a `isset` like function does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can't check if the variable is set. You can:

1. Initialize the variable that makes sense as an initial value -- such `0` for a counter, the maximal integer value if you're calculating a minimum, etc.
2. Initialize the variable to a value that you aren't going to use, for example `-1` if you're going to use unsigned integer values and an empty string for a string.
3. Introduce a boolean flag that indicates whether you have started doing something.

Answer (score 2):

Default for `int` will be `0` and for `string` will be `""`.

Comment: No, there are no default values. You probably meant default values for the contents of `int`- or `String` arrays, but that wouldn't be empty strings in case of `String[]`, but `null`'s.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: there are default values for fields, but not for local variables. String fields, like all the other Object fields, are initialized to null by default, and not not to "".

Comment: @JB, om my, my Java is getting rusty! Thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an Object instead of a primitive value, i.e.

```
Integer x = null;
...
public Integer getX(){
   if(x == null) {
      x = new Integer(10);
   }
   return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your functions for that control because each object has own rules about "isset() result" ;

Examples :

```
    public static final boolean isEmpty(String x) {
        return (x == null || x.trim().equals(""));
    }
    public static final boolean isEmpty(Integer x) {
        return (x == null || x == 0);
    }
    public static final boolean isEmpty(Long x) {
        return (x == null || x == 0);
    }
    public static final boolean isEmpty(Collection<?> x) {
        return (x == null || x.size() == 0);
    }
    public static final boolean isEmpty(Map<?,?> x) {
        return (x == null || x.size() == 0);
    }
    public static final boolean isEmpty(Object[] x) {
        return (x == null || x.length == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common use case of wanting to have an undefined value is when retrieving information from a data source.  In any given SQL query, you are likely to have records that have integers whose values is 0, but which can also be empty/null fields.  The same goes for strings, where an empty string '' is not the same as an undefined or null string.

It appears that using the object reference versions of native types is the only solution here, which is unfortunate since it's messy.  The alternative would be to store a boolean for every single data field that has to be checked and maintained by hand, which is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

The integer variable declared in java ,cannot undergo the condition for `"undefined"` or `"null"`.But by the use of the `wrapper class` we can make use of it i.e: `Integer a = null;`

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer max = null; //works perfectly
        int max1 == null; //throws and incompatible error 
        if (max == null)
            System.out.println("null");
    }
}
```