# Is there any method in java which does the same thing as isset() in php?

Tags: java, php, methods

Basically I have a if..else logic as below

```
if(request.getParameter("action")=="delete" && request.getParameter("action")!=null)  
{
   //delete operation
}
else
{
  //update operation
}
```

But during update process "action" parameter do not get attached with URL and hence NullPoitnerException is thrown.

Any solution to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate question [How to test if a variable is set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703622/how-to-test-if-a-variable-is-set)

Comment: Interesting where do you get NullPoitnerException? Even if `getParameter("action")` will return `null` you can not get this exception in your `if-conditions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `request.getParameter(x)` returns *null* when `x` is not set, you could simply swap the two conditions in your if-clause.

Thus

```
if(request.getParameter("action")=="delete" && request.getParameter("action")!=null)
```

would become

```
if(request.getParameter("action")!=null && request.getParameter("action")=="delete")
```

Since `&&` is a [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) *Boolean And* in Java, this will cause the the second half of the statement to be executed only if the part before the `&&` evaluates to *true* - thereby preventing your NullPointerException.

`request.getParameter("action")=="delete"` is a comparison with a string literal, though. You are most likely better off using [`.equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In **Java 8** you can do like this

```
Optional<String> paramOptional=Optional.ofNullable(request.getParameter());
        paramOptional.ifPresent(param->{
            //Do something with param
        });
 OR
 String param =paramOptional.orElse("you else string");//if null then this string will be return
```